# What word describes a group of which the speaker is not a part?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, connotation

I'm looking for a less clunky way of saying "a group of which I'm not a part" or "a group to I don't belong." I would prefer a one-word adjective, so that I could talk about "________ groups."

So far, the closest word to what I'm looking for seems to be *outlying*:

> Outlying (adjective):
>
> Far away from the center of a place; remote from a center or main body. ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outlying))

This would fit the fact that the group is figuratively far away from me because I'm not a part of it, but I hesitate to use it because it also seems to imply that the group is an outlier from the norm, an extreme or "fringe" group. This connotation is supported by [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/outlying?s=t)'s secondary definition:

> Outlying (adjective):
>
> 1. Lying at a distance from the center or the main body; remote; out-of-the way
> 2. Lying outside the boundary or limit

Is there a better adjective than *outlying* to describe any group, whether mainstream or fringe, to which I don't belong?

**EDIT: Here is the context that I would put the word in.**

> Studies have shown that people are more likely to be suspicious of members of __________ groups and attribute negative qualities to them while overlooking the same qualities in members of their own group.

Comment: Are you saying that _you_ are central, and the other members of the group are distant?

Comment: I'm not a part of the group at all, so the members of the group are distant from me.

Comment: *non-member* / *unsubscribed* / *outside* groups?

Comment: In a military sense a General could use *irregulars* or *partisans*, to make it clear that they were nothing to do with him.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Is there a specific foreign word or phrase you think would work here?

Comment: @Nicole sorry, I got distracted and didn't finish my comment. I was going to say, this is where English needs to take more influence from foreign languages and string words together. Then we could call them something like *not-member-groups* in one word, and nobody would bat an eyelid. There isn't a particular foreign word I was thinking of.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Okay, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Nicole - OK then your title and suggested words of outlier are very much at odds. An outlier is a member of a group just not very representative of the properties of the group, a short person on a basketball team. Very much part of the group, but special in the sense that they are not near the center of the group. You however are looking for a word that just says 'here is a group. I am not a member of this group at all'. Tall or short, you are just not a member of the basketball team. Is that right?

Comment: @Mitch That's right. If there are Groups A, B, and C, and I belong only to Group A, what adjective could I use to describe Group B and Group C?

Comment: Nicole: Then what you want is maybe simply "another group". The semantics of 'another' implies that it is not your group, not a group you are in. This would be a lot easier if you gave a longer fuller sentence so we can see how it should sound. 'Outlier' is very misleading/is not what you want.

Comment: I edited my question to show how I'll be using the word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the word "outgroup", which is used in the social sciences as a term to refer to a social group you are not a member of without any implication of the group being "fringe". It's not an adjective, but "outgroup" can like most nouns be used to modify another noun, like "outgroup relationships". If you need to talk about multiple groups, you could simply use the plural "outgroups".

Comment: Yup. Ingroups and outgroups were the first thing that came to my mind as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to them as *[external](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/external)* groups:

> **1.** coming from outside a place or organization

I would have suggested *[remote](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/remote_1)*, but current business usage implies that you are part of a *remote team*.